# Database not storing data from form

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my html, code check it if there is any error

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Add Team </title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/thickbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="javascript"> 
        var RE = /^.+@.+\..{3}$/;
        var RE1 = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        var RE2 = /^[0-9]{10}$/;

        function validateForm()
        {
        if (document.f1.pname.value == "")
        {
        window.alert(" Name should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.pname.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (RE1.test(document.f1.pname.value) == false)
        {
        alert("Invalid format");
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.pname.value.length < 6)
        {
        window.alert("name must have atleast SIX characters");
        document.f1.pname.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.role.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("role should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.role.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (RE1.test(document.f1.role.value) == false)
        {
        alert("INvalid format");
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.role.value.length < 6)
        {
        window.alert("role must have atleast SIX  characters");
        document.f1.role.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.role.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("role should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.role.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.education.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("education should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.education.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (RE1.test(document.f1.education.value) == false)
        {
        alert("INvalid format");
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.education.value.length < 6)
        {
        window.alert("education must have atleast SIX characters");
        document.f1.education.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.education.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("education should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.education.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.hobbies.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("hobbies should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.hobbies.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (RE1.test(document.f1.hobbies.value) == false)
        {
        alert("INvalid format");
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.hobbies.value.length < 6)
        {
        window.alert("hobbies must have atleast SIX characters");
        document.f1.hobbies.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.hobbies.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("hobbeis should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.hobbies.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.best.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("what is your best one liner should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.best.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (RE1.test(document.f1.best.value) == false)
        {
        alert("INvalid format");
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.best.value.length < 6)
        {
        window.alert("what is your best one liner must have atleast SIX characters");
        document.f1.best.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.best.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("what is your best one liner should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.best.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.look.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("who do they say you look like should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.look.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (RE1.test(document.f1.look.value) == false)
        {
        alert("INvalid format");
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.look.value.length < 6)
        {
        window.alert("who do they say you look like  must have atleast SIX characters");
        document.f1.look.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.look.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("who do they say you look like should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.look.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.role.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("role should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.role.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (RE1.test(document.f1.role.value) == false)
        {
        alert("INvalid format");
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.role.value.length < 6)
        {
        window.alert("role must have atleast SIX characters");
        document.f1.role.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        if (document.f1.role.value == "")
        {
        window.alert("role should NOT BE empty");
        document.f1.role.focus();
        return false;
        }
        else
        {
        window.alert("ur entire Given input is valid..");
        return true;
        }

        }
    </script></head>
<body>
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" >

            <tr>
        <form name="f1" method="post"  onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="connect.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><strong>Team Member </strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="78">Name</td>
                        <td width="6">:</td>
                        <td width="294"><input name="pname" type="text" id="t1" onblur="pname_validateForm();"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Role</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="role" type="text" id="t2" onblur="role_validateForm();"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Profile Image</td><td>:</td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="file_upload" id="upload_file" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Education</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="education" type="text" id="t3" onblur="education_validateForm();"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hobbies</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="hobbies" type="text" id="t4" onblur="hobbies_validateForm();"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>What is your best one liner?</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="best" type="text" id="t5" onblur="best_validateForm();"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Who do they say you look like?</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="look" type="text" id="t6" onblur="look_validateForm();"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>What people do not like about me?</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="about" type="text" id="t7" onblur="about_validateForm();"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input name="submit" class="btn_login" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
             </form>
       </table>
```

Here is my database connection code i don't know why it was not storing the registration form  data in database but simply showing some blank page

I  tried many times but it won't work please help me to find out error :

```
   <?php
```

Here is the database connections :

```
       $host = "localhost"; // Host name
       $username = "root"; // Mysql username
        $password = ""; // Mysql password
       $db_name = "project"; // Database name
```

Connect to server and select database :

```
     mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
     mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
```

Checking the image type and get the image from form :

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $target = "../uploads/";
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg");
    $value = explode(".", $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]);
    $extension = strtolower(array_pop($value));
    //$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]));
    $target = $target . basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);

    //$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //Function to generate image thumbnails
     function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

      /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
      $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination with 100% quality */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest, 100);
}

  // Get values from form
    $pname = $_POST['pname'];
    $role = $_POST['role'];
    $pimg = @$_POST['file_upload'];
    $education = $_POST['education'];
    $hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'];
    $best = $_POST['best'];
    $look = $_POST['look'];
    $about = $_POST['about'];

 //check for allowed extensions
if ((($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    $photoname = $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"];
    if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $pimg)) {
        die('<div class="error">Sorry <b>' . $pimg . '</b> already exists</div>');
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        //$query = "INSERT INTO photos (image,) VALUES ('$photoname','$date')";
        $query = "INSERT INTO teams(name,role,pimg,education,hobbies,best,look,about)VALUES('$pname','$role','$pimg','$education','$hobbies','$best','$look','$about')";
        mysql_query($query);
        $sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos";
        $max = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($max);
        $maxId = $row['MAX(id)'];

        $type = $_FILES["file_upload"]["type"];
        switch ($type) {
            case "image/jpeg":
                $ext = ".jpeg";
                break;
            case "image/jpg";
                $ext = ".jpg";
                break;
        }

        //define arguments for the make_thumb function
        $source = "../uploads/" . $photoname;
        $destination = "../thumbnails/thumb_" . $maxId . $ext . "";
        //specify your desired width for your thumbnails
        $width = "282";
        //Finally call the make_thumb function
        make_thumb($source, $destination, $width);

        $msg = '<div class="success">
                    <b>Upload: </b>' . basename($photoname) . '<br />
                    <b>Type: </b>' . $_FILES["file_upload"]["type"] . '<br />
                    <b>Size: </b>' . ceil(($_FILES["file_upload"]["size"] / 1024)) . 'Kb<br />
                </div>';
    } else {
        $msg = '<div class="error">Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.</div>';
    }
} else {
    $msg = '<div class="error">The file type you are trying to upload is not allowed!</div>';
}
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: You should never use the `root` account for database connection in a web app.

Comment: Turn on the errors & check what error you getting.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @SureshKamrushi: As stated, he got a blank page.

Comment: NO i am not getting error but simply it shows blank page

Comment: Just now i added, if there is any changes or errors in it inform me.. and please help me to find out solution...

Comment: Ganesh you should really check user input serverside (PHP) and not clientside (javascript) because it can be altered after javascript handles it.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the path to the file and not relative paths when dealing with uploads.

```
$target = "../uploads/";
```

It should contain the path to the folder since this is a relative path to the script executing the commands. (Something like this depending on the exact location of the target folder.)

```
$target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
```

Additionally this file should have the path as well:

```
$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/thumbnails/thumb_" . $maxId . $ext . "";
```

Also this should not include the @ sign and it should be the name of the file, so you can pull that from the `$_FILES` array:

```
$pimg = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
```

For testing you can print the output of the `$_FILES` array to make sure you're capturing the right array key(index) fields if the problem still exists after the change. Since the undefined index error means the value you're trying to pull isn't in the array.

```
print_r($_FILE);
```

Comment: but if i remove the @symbol it showing some notice as Undefined Index.

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';   I tried this but the form has been changed it not showing the submit button...

Comment: That should be for the paths where you're handling the files. I've updated my response.

Comment: The blank page is a PHP error. Have you tried adding this as a test?
`ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`